# Stripe/Laravel "This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method."

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

There are multiple people on here who've had the same problem, except all posts I could find on here regarding this issue with the Stripe API are from a deprecated version of Stripe, and the code seems to have changed entirely so their attachment of payment method doesn't work for me. I have, almost word for word, the code directly from the Laravel cashier documentation.

Currently it looks as such on the client-side;

```
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            const stripe = Stripe('mystripekey');

            const elements = stripe.elements();
            const cardElement = elements.create('card');

            cardElement.mount('#card-element');

            const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
            const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
            const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;

            cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
                const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
                    clientSecret, {
                        payment_method: {
                            card: cardElement,
                            billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                        }
                    }
                );
                if (error) {
                    // Display "error.message" to the user...
                } else {
                    alert("it works");
                    $("#paymentForm").submit();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="mt-5 border border-secondary rounded container w-25">
        <h3 class="mt-3 text-left font-weight-bold">Upgrade Account</h3>
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PaymentController@paymentLeadUser', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'paymentForm']) !!}
            @csrf
                <input value="user_premium" type="hidden">
                <label for="card-holder-name">Card Holder Name:</label>
                <input id="card-holder-name" class="w-100 mb-3" name="card-holder-name" type="text">
                <!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
                <div id="card-element" class="form-control"></div>

                <button id="card-button" class="my-4 btn btn-primary"data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
                    Upgrade to Premium
                </button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
@endsection
```

My Controller has this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function paymentPage() {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $data = [

            'intent' => $user->createSetupIntent()

        ];

        return view('payment')->with($data);
    }

    public function paymentLeadUser(Request $request) {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $paymentMethod = $request->payment_method;

        $user->newSubscription('default', 'plan_id')->create($paymentMethod);

        return redirect('/userlanding')->with('success', 'User has subscribed successfully!');
    }
}
```

I don't know why it isn't working, it should be successful but for some reason it isn't...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's a bit tricky to debug this with the code because Laravel abstracts a lot of Stripe's API away from you. The problem, based on the error here, is that the Customer you're trying to subscribe to a plan, doesn't have a valid PaymentMethod attached. You should be able to confirm this in the Dashboard. Also add some logs to your code to confirm that `$paymentMethod` is not empty today and that this card has been attached to the customer already (it likely hasn't if the SetupIntent is not configured to save a card)

Comment: True as far as the Laravel hiding, I went back through Stripe's entire documentation and reformatted the code and it's now in a better situation because I'm only getting an error log that says: "Received unknown parameters: object, billing_details, card, created, livemode, type" now. I'll update the post to show the new code. It's also creating a customer, starts a payment then cancels it when the server code fails.

Comment: @Nathan which version of laravel and laravel-cashier you're using?